# Disasters and no maintenance techs

Tags: surviving-mars

There are several techs in the game, which eliminate the maintenance need for certain buildings (e.g. superior cables/pipes, autonomous hubs/sensors).

Do those techs also protect the buildings from being destroyed by disasters (e.g. a direct meteor strike)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, a meteor strike is a sure kill for an external building if it is in the impact zone